# Ubuntu Openstack - uninstall error

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

I tried installing ubuntu openstack using conjure-up but I have completely messed it up.I tried uninstalling using conjure-down but getting the following error

" nonetype" object has no attribute  controller'

I would like to remove all the files and sart over. Attached is the log file ..just in case.[conjure up log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a17nG5DoKc7MD1vuYnRZV2QseACxfWnp/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer since I could resolve the issue using a workaround. Just in case somebody is interested.
I used the following command to destroy the juju environment 
juju destroy-environment

Then I was able to run conjure-up again.